# Canvas problems. Not able to reproduce design

Tags: javascript, canvas, reward

I need to build canvas animation like design requires. I spend almost 3 days but I'm not able to do anything like in design. Here a REQUESTED [design!](https://www.videosprout.com/video?id=990dc940-692d-4300-b300-9e4e2a585f74). And here - what I've got for now: [current implementation](https://www.videosprout.com/video?id=6317309f-1fa0-44d0-be1f-6b38e01d7f3c) which definitely not what requested from design .I need only animation of planet from particles at background (also whole process of animation changes in time, it starts from few particles but then amount growing and movings directions of particles changes)

here my current code:

```js
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {

  sphereRad = 280;
  radius_sp = 1;
  distance = 600;
  particle_size = 0.7;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvasApp();
  }

  canvasApp () {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    let displayWidth;
    let displayHeight;
    let wait;
    let count;
    let numToAddEachFrame;
    let particleList;
    let recycleBin;
    let particleAlpha;
    let r, g, b;
    let fLen;
    let m;
    let projCenterX;
    let projCenterY;
    let zMax;
    let turnAngle;
    let turnSpeed;
    let sphereCenterX, sphereCenterY, sphereCenterZ;
    let particleRad;
    let zeroAlphaDepth;
    let randAccelX, randAccelY, randAccelZ;
    let gravity;
    let rgbString;
    // we are defining a lot of letiables used in the screen update functions globally so that they don't have to be redefined every frame.
    let p;
    let outsideTest;
    let nextParticle;
    let sinAngle;
    let cosAngle;
    let rotX, rotZ;
    let depthAlphaFactor;
    let i;
    let theta, phi;
    let x0, y0, z0;

    // INITIALLI
    const init = () => {
      wait = 1;
      count = wait - 1;
      numToAddEachFrame = 30;

      // particle color
      r = 255;
      g = 255;
      b = 255;

      rgbString = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ','; // partial string for color which will be completed by appending alpha value.
      particleAlpha = 1; // maximum alpha

      displayWidth = canvas.width;
      displayHeight = canvas.height;

      fLen = this.distance; // represents the distance from the viewer to z=0 depth.

      // projection center coordinates sets location of origin
      projCenterX = displayWidth / 2;
      projCenterY = displayHeight / 2;

      // we will not draw coordinates if they have too large of a z-coordinate (which means they are very close to the observer).
      zMax = fLen - 2;

      particleList = {};
      recycleBin = {};

      // random acceleration factors - causes some random motion
      randAccelX = 0.1;
      randAccelY = 0.1;
      randAccelZ = 0.1;

      gravity = -0; // try changing to a positive number (not too large, for example 0.3), or negative for floating upwards.

      particleRad = this.particle_size;

      sphereCenterX = 0;
      sphereCenterY = 0;
      sphereCenterZ = -3 - this.sphereRad;

      // alpha values will lessen as particles move further back, causing depth-based darkening:
      zeroAlphaDepth = 0;

      turnSpeed = 2 * Math.PI / 1200; // the sphere will rotate at this speed (one complete rotation every 1600 frames).
      turnAngle = 0; // initial angle

      // timer = setInterval(onTimer, 10 / 24);
      onTimer();
    }

    const onTimer = () => {
      // if enough time has elapsed, we will add new particles.
      count++;
      if (count >= wait) {

        count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < numToAddEachFrame; i++) {
          theta = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
          phi = Math.acos(Math.random() * 2 - 1);
          x0 = this.sphereRad * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
          y0 = this.sphereRad * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
          z0 = this.sphereRad * Math.cos(phi);

          // We use the addParticle function to add a new particle. The parameters set the position and velocity components.
          // Note that the velocity parameters will cause the particle to initially fly outwards away from the sphere center (after
          // it becomes unstuck).
          const p = addParticle(x0, sphereCenterY + y0, sphereCenterZ + z0, 0.002 * x0, 0.002 * y0, 0.002 * z0);

          // we set some 'envelope' parameters which will control the evolving alpha of the particles.
          p.attack = 50;
          p.hold = 50;
          p.decay = 100;
          p.initValue = 0;
          p.holdValue = particleAlpha;
          p.lastValue = 0;

          // the particle will be stuck in one place until this time has elapsed:
          p.stuckTime = 90 + Math.random() * 20;

          p.accelX = 0;
          p.accelY = gravity;
          p.accelZ = 0;
        }
      }

      // update viewing angle
      turnAngle = (turnAngle + turnSpeed) % (2 * Math.PI);
      sinAngle = Math.sin(turnAngle);
      cosAngle = Math.cos(turnAngle);

      // background fill
      context.fillStyle = '#000000';
      context.fillRect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

      // update and draw particles
      p = particleList.first;
      while (p != null) {
        // before list is altered record next particle
        nextParticle = p.next;

        // update age
        p.age++;

        // if the particle is past its 'stuck' time, it will begin to move.
        if (p.age > p.stuckTime) {
          p.velX += p.accelX + randAccelX * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
          p.velY += p.accelY + randAccelY * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);
          p.velZ += p.accelZ + randAccelZ * (Math.random() * 2 - 1);

          p.x += p.velX;
          p.y += p.velY;
          p.z += p.velZ;
        }

        /*
              We are doing two things here to calculate display coordinates.
              The whole display is being rotated around a vertical axis, so we first calculate rotated coordinates for
              x and z (but the y coordinate will not change).
              Then, we take the new coordinates (rotX, y, rotZ), and project these onto the 2D view plane.
              */
        rotX =  cosAngle * p.x + sinAngle * (p.z - sphereCenterZ);
        rotZ =  -sinAngle * p.x + cosAngle * (p.z - sphereCenterZ) + sphereCenterZ;
        // m = this.radius_sp * fLen / (fLen - rotZ);
        m = this.radius_sp;
        p.projX = rotX * m + projCenterX;
        p.projY = p.y * m + projCenterY;
        p.projZ = rotZ * m + projCenterX;
        // update alpha according to envelope parameters.
        if (p.age < p.attack + p.hold + p.decay) {
          if (p.age < p.attack) {
            p.alpha = (p.holdValue - p.initValue) / p.attack * p.age + p.initValue;
          } else if (p.age < p.attack + p.hold) {
            p.alpha = p.holdValue;
          } else if (p.age < p.attack + p.hold + p.decay) {
            p.alpha = (p.lastValue - p.holdValue) / p.decay * (p.age - p.attack - p.hold) + p.holdValue;
          }
        } else {
          p.dead = true;
        }

        // see if the particle is still within the viewable range.
        if ((p.projX > displayWidth) || (p.projX < 0) || (p.projY < 0) || (p.projY > displayHeight) || (rotZ > zMax)) {
          outsideTest = true;
        } else {
          outsideTest = false;
        }
        if (outsideTest || p.dead ||
          (p.projX  > displayWidth / (2 + (1 - Math.random())) && p.projZ + displayWidth * 0.1  > displayWidth / 2) ||
          (p.projX < displayWidth / (2 - (1 - Math.random()))  && p.projZ + displayWidth * 0.25  < displayWidth / 2)
        ) {
          recycle(p);
        } else {
          // depth-dependent darkening
          // console.log(turnAngle, rotZ)
          depthAlphaFactor = 1;
          // depthAlphaFactor = (1 - (1.5 + rotZ / 100));
          depthAlphaFactor = (depthAlphaFactor > 1) ? 1 : ((depthAlphaFactor < 0) ? 0 : depthAlphaFactor);
          context.fillStyle = rgbString + depthAlphaFactor * p.alpha + ')';
          // draw
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(p.projX, p.projY, m * particleRad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.closePath();
          context.fill();
        }

        p = nextParticle;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onTimer);
    }

    const addParticle = (x0, y0, z0, vx0, vy0, vz0) => {
      let newParticle;
      // const color;


      // check recycle bin for available drop:
      if (recycleBin.first != null) {
        newParticle = recycleBin.first;
        // remove from bin
        if (newParticle.next != null) {
          recycleBin.first = newParticle.next;
          newParticle.next.prev = null;
        } else {
          recycleBin.first = null;
        }
      } else {
        newParticle = {};
      }
      // if the recycle bin is empty, create a new particle (a new empty object):
      // add to beginning of particle list
      if (particleList.first == null) {
        particleList.first = newParticle;
        newParticle.prev = null;
        newParticle.next = null;
      } else {
        newParticle.next = particleList.first;
        particleList.first.prev = newParticle;
        particleList.first = newParticle;
        newParticle.prev = null;
      }

      // initialize
      newParticle.x = x0;
      newParticle.y = y0;
      newParticle.z = z0;
      newParticle.velX = vx0;
      newParticle.velY = vy0;
      newParticle.velZ = vz0;
      newParticle.age = 0;
      newParticle.dead = false;

      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        newParticle.right = true;
      } else {
        newParticle.right = false;
      }
      return newParticle;
    }

    const recycle = (p) => {
      // remove from particleList
      if (particleList.first === p) {
        if (p.next != null) {
          p.next.prev = null;
          particleList.first = p.next;
        } else {
          particleList.first = null;
        }
      } else {
        if (p.next == null) {
          p.prev.next = null;
        } else {
          p.prev.next = p.next;
          p.next.prev = p.prev;
        }
      }
      // add to recycle bin
      if (recycleBin.first == null) {
        recycleBin.first = p;
        p.prev = null;
        p.next = null;
      } else {
        p.next = recycleBin.first;
        recycleBin.first.prev = p;
        recycleBin.first = p;
        p.prev = null;
      }
    };
    init();
  }
}
```

So I will be happy with any help also REWARD(for full implementation) is possible (ETH, BTC any currency you wish).